# How do I integrate this shape in 3D given as the area in between $z=\sqrt 2$ $;z=x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Integrating the are inside $x>0, y>0;z=\sqrt 2;\ \ \ z=x^2+y^2;\ \ \ x^2+y^2+z^2=2$

I have a picture. I figured out how to find the area of shape $G_1$ as $$\int_{1}^{\sqrt 2}dz\int_{1}^{\sqrt z}dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z-x^2}}dy.$$ I can't seem to find the set for $G_2$ in this manner. Help? Picture follows:[image]

Do I have to divide $G_2$ in  a couple of areas as well to get a set that can be presented as $$G_2=\{1 \leq z \leq \sqrt{2} ; f_2(z)\leq x \leq f_2(z); f_3(x,z)\leq y \leq f_4(x,z)  \}$$
I have a exam coming up in two days, so I really need to get this 3D integrating down. Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to find the *volume* of the described region, and are not integrating some function over that region.

The region is the first-octant part of region between the two surfaces:

[image]

Your region $G_1$ seems to be the upper portion, above the ring-shaped intersection of the surfaces up to the top of the sphere. Some of your limits on $G_1$ are incorrect. You are right that $1\le z\le \sqrt 2$, since one can show that the circular intersection happens at $z=1$ and the top of the sphere is at $z=\sqrt 2$. However, the limits on $x$ are given by the inequlity $x\ge 0$ and the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ where $y=0$, namely $0\le x\le\sqrt{2-z^2}$. The resulting limits on $y$ come from the inequality $y\ge 0$ and the same equation: $0\le y\le\sqrt{2-z^2-x^2}$. Therefore your integral should be

$$G_1=\int_1^{\sqrt 2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2-z^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{2-z^2-x^2}}dy\,dx\,dz$$

The limits on $G_2$, the paraboloid below the circular intersection, are similar but based on the equation $z=x^2+y^2$. $z$ goes from $0$ to $1$. The limits on $x$ are given from zero to where $y=0$, and the limits on $y$ come from the equation. The integral is

$$G_2=\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt z}\int_0^{\sqrt{z-x^2}}dy\,dx\,dz$$

However, I would not recommend finding the volumes by that method. Better would be using cylindrical coordinates, or the equivalent of using the method of disks to find the volume in all four octants above $z=0$ and dividing the result by four. Let me know if you need details.

Comment: I will take a look at this in the morning, I thank you for the detailed answer.